# How to bind variable inside ASPxTextBox's NullText

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, devexpress

I have some TextBox with NullText attribute (AspxTextBox). I want to bind variable value inside NullText but it's not working.

`<dx:ASPxTextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" NullText="<%=Resources.MyResources.Email%>" />`

The result is always'Resources.MyResources.Email' as a string therefore when i put the same Resource Value outside the NullText, it worked like expected.

Comment: did you try `NullText="<%# Resources.MyResources.Email %>"`?

Comment: Thank's for the comment, yes i did and i got a blank result unfortunately it's not binding the real value (the value exist and it's not a blank string i'm displaying it outside the NullText)